# What does double dash (--) implies in Selenium ChromeOptions

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, chrome-options

I am using selenium with java and I am using some chrome options with it. But I see different usages of chrome options in different sources. I mean some folks using double dash before the option and some do not (like `disable-dev-shm-usage` and `--disable-dev-shm-usage`). Are there any differences between the two usages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Command-Line Options](https://web.archive.org/web/20090125095309/http://catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s05.html):

> Unix tradition encourages the use of command-line switches to control
>   programs, so that options can be specified from scripts. There are
>   three conventions to distinguish command-line options from ordinary
>   arguments as follows:
>
> - The original Unix style
> - The GNU style
> - The X toolkit style
>
> The GNU style uses option keywords (rather than keyword letters)
>   preceded by two hyphens. It evolved years later when some of the
>   rather elaborate GNU utilities began to run out of single-letter
>   option keys (this constituted a patch for the symptom, not a cure for
>   the underlying disease). It remains popular because GNU options are
>   easier to read than the alphabet soup of older styles. GNU-style
>   options cannot be ganged together without separating whitespace.

The GNU double-hyphen option leader was chosen so that traditional single-letter options and GNU-style keyword options could be unambiguously mixed on the same command line.

Comment: So with or without hyphens, the option keyword will work, right? Hyphens using only for readability?

Comment: @rdonuk Precisely, yes