# Undetected Chromedriver not loading correctly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm attempting to use a headless chrome browser with selenium that also bypasses the bot detection test and currently using the the following project https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver
Every time I try to implement the code it doesn't recognise the driver.
[Here is the link for you to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUGPY.png)

Here is the code

```
#
# UNDETECTED chromedriver (headless,even)
#
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.headless=True
options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome = uc.Chrome(options=options)
chrome.get('https://datadome.co/customers-stories/toppreise-ends-web-scraping-and-content-theft-with-datadome/')
chrome.save_screenshot('datadome_undetected_webddriver.png')
```

So when I use `chrome.get()` I receive an error as chrome has no `get()` member.
I've installed the project using the pip command as well. So I was thinking do I need to direct  the path to the chromedriver and where would that be because I doubt it'll be the normal driver and the documentation never mentioned the PATH for the driver.

Okay so when I run the program I get the following in terminal

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55903/devtools/browser/ef3a54cf-35b9-400f-972c-2b54ca227eb8
[0102/000855.199:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1", source: https://datadome.co/wp-content/cache/busting/1/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min-1.4.1.js (2)
[0102/000856.946:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Messaging child iframes", source: https://track.gaconnector.com/gaconnector.js (1)
[0102/000856.946:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "https://track.gaconnector.com/track_pageview?gaconnector_id=ddade4fc-93d0-20a3-79fa-39648d8e6629&account_id=6dd3433635353fd00f486550bcd5b157&referer=&GA_Client_ID=183291439.1609510136&page_url=https%3A%2F%2Fdatadome.co%2Fcustomers-stories%2Ftoppreise-ends-web-scraping-and-content-theft-with-datadome%2F&gclid=&utm_campaign=&utm_term=&utm_content=&utm_source=&utm_medium=", source: https://track.gaconnector.com/gaconnector.js (1)
PS D:\Programming\Python> [0102/000902.158:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://js.driftt.com/core/assets/js/runtime~main.a73a2727.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source: https://js.driftt.com/core?embedId=2rce7xnshapc&forceShow=false&skipCampaigns=false&sessionId=98163ad1-ed91-459e-9473-3f8861aa717e&sessionStarted=1609510138&campaignRefreshToken=107a7fd5-edb4-499b-9f39-5306c189cdb6&pageLoadStartTime=1609510135613 (0)
[0102/000902.272:ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(224)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
[0102/000902.272:ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(224)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
[0102/000902.475:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://js.driftt.com/core/assets/js/runtime~main.a73a2727.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source: https://js.driftt.com/core/chat (0)
[0102/000906.041:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://js.zohocdn.com/ichat/js/73291e5e_wmsbridge.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source: https://datadome.co/customers-stories/toppreise-ends-web-scraping-and-content-theft-with-datadome/ (0)
```

Comment: I've added chrome driver to the variable PATH and still nothing. I've even have it as parameters "options = uc.ChromeOptions('D:/Programming/chromedriver.exe')"

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not commnt) as ext not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`ChromeOptions()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60039687/what-does-double-dash-implies-in-selenium-chromeoptions) is defined within  [selenium.webdriver.chrome.options](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options) but not within [undetected_chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver).

---

### Solution

You can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import undetected_chromedriver as uc
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.headless = True
  driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get('https://datadome.co/customers-stories/toppreise-ends-web-scraping-and-content-theft-with-datadome/')
  driver.save_screenshot('datadome_undetected_webddriver.png')
  driver.quit()
  print("Program Ended")
  ```
- Console Output:

[image: undetected_chromedriver]

- Screenshot:

[image: datadome_undetected_webddriver]

---

### References

You canfind a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Is there any possible ways to bypass cloudflare security checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328849/is-there-any-possible-ways-to-bypass-cloudflare-security-checks/64960388#64960388)

Comment: For future readers: in the newest version 2.2.1, I can just use ChromeOptions from UC without any problem, so we don't need to use chrome option from Selenium. There are fixes in ChromeOptions of UC, so we should use this option instead of Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

ChromeOptions is defined in the undetected_chromedriver now. You can access it as:

```
undetected_chromedriver.options.ChromeOptions()
```