# How to bypass Selenium Block Find Element

Tags: javascript, selenium, findelement

If I use find.element by anything (xpath, id, name, etc.), somehow the website can detect that and block my actions. When I take lines with find.element away, code works as intended. Are there any ways to bypass this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65529808/undetected-chromedriver-not-loading-correctly/65534593#65534593) discussion helps you?

Comment: tried all the suggestions, still doesnt work. I think its site can detect any find.element for some reason? I came to this conclusion because if I just open up the site in selenium chrome driver and click everything manually, the site functions as intended. However, if I click while having inspect element open, it gets detected.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/70133896#70133896) discussion help you?

Comment: just tried stealth, still doenst work. It gets detected when I try to submit a form. Perhaps its something server side? I think it has to be something to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49782328/17500343). I couldnt try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53632873/17500343) as I dont know how to edit the javscript codes.

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.