# Open blocked site for scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to scrape a few details from a website and the problem is that the particular website is banned in India and I cannot open the site without a VPN but the VPN makes scrapping a lot slower and the program crashes a lot because the response time of the site increases. Is there any other way I can access the website?

Comment: You could try using public proxies of the site

Comment: Have to tried using [**undetected_chromedriver**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65534593/7429447) or [**selenium-stealth**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70133896/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, It's a private DNS that lets you access blocked websites. It is Faster and Better than a VPN.

Works only on Chrome:

1. Go to Chrome Settings.
2. Click on Security.
3. On the secure DNS, select Cloudflare (1.1.1.1).

For more details: https://asapguide.com/open-blocked-websites-without-vpn/

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrape API https://www.scraperapi.com/ it provides you with a dynamic IP. It supports all the languages, you only need to attach the URL of scraper API at the beginning and your URL as param.