# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden undetected-chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, urllib3, undetected-chromedriver

When I try to use Selenium, it gives an error in the first lines of the code

code:

```
driverLocation = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
binaryLocation = "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"

chrome_options = Options()
dir = r"/home/ubuntu/.config/google-chrome/Default"
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={dir}")
chrome_options.binary_location = binaryLocation
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')


driver = UC.Chrome(executable_path=driverLocation, options=chrome_options)
```

error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    driver = UC.Chrome(executable_path=driverLocation, options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 233, in __init__
    patcher.auto()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/patcher.py", line 130, in auto
    self.unzip_package(self.fetch_package())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/patcher.py", line 166, in fetch_package
    return urlretrieve(u)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve  
     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

And when I use Selenium web driver, it doesn't give this error (it only happens when I use undetected-chromedriver)

I run this code on Ubuntu 20.04 server with Chrome 103
And some of my servers do not give this error
And I set up all the servers in the same way

Answer (score -1):

Apart from importing *webdriver*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

you also have to import [*`undetected_chromedriver`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65534593/7429447) as:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as UC
```

and then only you can use:

```
driver = UC.Chrome(executable_path=driverLocation, options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: I have already imported these